# Multiple independent sets of bootstrap tabs with tabbed content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have multiple independent sets of tabbed content on one page. So far when I click a tab the active content in the second area disappears as well.

```
<div>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#foo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Foo</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#bar" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="foo">Foo content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="bar">Bar content</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#foo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Foo</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#bar" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="foo">Foo content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="bar">Bar content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All ids need to be unique across the document. Rename the id=foo and id=bar divs as well as their respective anchor toggles to fix the problem.